# GRUB Bootloader with root LUKS encryption: Only grub shell

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, disk-encryption

I would appreciate help and hints to solve a problem with the GRUB bootloader. 
I have a system with root LUKS encryption. Means that except the partition with the bootloader, the whole system is in an encrypted LUKS container. I am unsure where the possible problems are, so I tell you some more details.

After a system update, GRUB now hangs in the GRUB shell (not rescue mode).

I can however start manually with:

```
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
cryptomount -a
set root=(lvm/system-root)
linux (lvm/system-boot)/vmlinuz-[...]-generic root=/dev/system/root
initrd (lvm/system-boot)/initrd.img-[...]-generic
```

Running lsblk on my system looks like this:

```
nvme0n1           259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1       259:1    0   450M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p2       259:2    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3       259:3    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p4       259:4    0  97,9G  0 part
└─nvme0n1p5       259:5    0 839,4G  0 part
  └─system        253:0    0 839,4G  0 crypt
    ├─system-boot 253:1    0   512M  0 lvm   /boot
    ├─system-swap 253:2    0  16,1G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─system-root 253:3    0 822,8G  0 lvm   /
```

p1, p3, p4 belong to an installed windows 10.
p2 is the fat32 EFI system partition
p5 is the luks encrypted system with boot, swap and root partition.

### Maybe Grub cannot load the grub.cfg?

I thought Grub does not find the config file in the p2 partition in /boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg.

But if this would be the case, the manual execution of the config file should succeed. So I executed (used auto-completion, so the path should be right) in the grub shell at startup:

```
configfile (hd0,gpt2)/grub/grub.cfg
```

But i just get a cleared grub shell (without any errors).

Why I thought grub does not find the grub.cfg is because of the content of the grub config file in the EFI folder (which gets loaded first as I understood corecctly):
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg:

```
search.fs_uuid db041d94-37fa-42a6-b2f3-87572a38f23c root lvmid/uWUnvj-b70J-Gfam-Tfr3-87I3-GQAP-bL2Lym/gEpImK-yuWK-W6Ip-v5KF-ZGKm-8GZS-ALhXxF 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Here the UUID(list at the end) it looks for is the one of theencrypted boot partition. This seems weired: Shouldn't it be visible for grub till I entered the password?.

But as my command to load the config file manually did not work I guess this is not the issue for my problem.

### Checking /etc/default/grub

So it could be my configuration file:
I cannot judge how right this file is, so here is the summarized content of the file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=8d82f654-43fd-40ba-a185-1ead48838f54:system root=/dev/system/system-root resume=/dev/system/system-swap ro"

GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="luks cryptodisk lvm ext2"
```

To me this does not look too bad. The UUID of the cryptdevice looks fine. 
I tried changed the "/dev/system/system-root" to
"/dev/system/system" as this is the path while running the system, but without any effect.
i also did run update-grup and grub-install.

In addition I installed grub-emu (emulator for the grub bootloader).
This did show me at least the gurb menu. When selecting the entry to start ubuntu I get at least some errors:

```
error: no such cryptodisk found.
error: no such device: db041d94-37fa-42a6-b2f3-87572a38f23c.
error: can't find command `linux'.
error: can't find command `initrd'.
```

### What would help me

- Of course point me to the problem and telling me the fix.
  As I now have to deal with it, i am curious about the boot process with grub:
- I do not understand the content of the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.
- What is the content of ($root) here? And why is it looking for an encrypted partition?
- Where is it determined what content is in this file?
- Why does it not show me at least the grub menu even if there are errors that would prevent the system to boot?

Thank you very much,
Ecco

### Additional content

The content of /boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg can be found at https://pastebin.com/D1X7jPsS

#### UUIDs (i omitted the windows specific partitions)

- /dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="2885-45AC" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="1043df12-d11d-4023-bf6a-6acc2919c06f"
- /dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="8d82f654-43fd-40ba-a185-1ead48838f54" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="system" PARTUUID="2457b24a-7695-4737-ae46-5687aca3ab01"

#### UUIDs of the LUKS container

- /dev/mapper/system: UUID="X7XHJG-pQ21-edgj-d73H-kK8Z-DxM8-eXBCh6" TYPE="LVM2_member"
- /dev/mapper/system-root: LABEL="root" UUID="07e1d1e4-cd00-42dd-96cf-4f99864d0b7f" TYPE="ext4"
- /dev/mapper/system-swap: UUID="02664e3e-3ba7-4a03-8b03-eb0335ca40f9" TYPE="swap"
- /dev/mapper/system-boot: LABEL="boot" UUID="db041d94-37fa-42a6-b2f3-87572a38f23c" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: Do not know LVM nor encryption, but this seems to be same issue? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414561

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I did help me to find the solution - cool.

Answer (score 5):

Finally it works (again):
The cmd **refreshgrub** did the trick
This command changed the content of the file  /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to:

```
search.fs_uuid 2885-45AC root 
set prefix=($root)'/EFI/ubuntu/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

This makes more sense than before: Searching for the unencrypted partition. But now the bigger grub.cfg file is stored in another folder, which is ok.

It was now showing the menu, but the boot failed, I had to change in the /etc/default/grub.cfg the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=8d82f654-43fd-40ba-a185-1ead48838f54:system root=/dev/system/root resume=/dev/system/swap ro"
```

Comment: Change it from what to what?

Comment: It's now `grub-install --uefi-secure-boot --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --recheck` and that generates the proper EFI config for Secure Boot GRUB with LUKS root.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the commands listed above, it didn't work for me, so I ended up downloading the grub rescue CD from here:
Download grub rescue

I burnt the CD image to a flash disk with the following command:

```
 sudo dd if=/home/User/Downloads/supergrub2-2.06s1-beta2-multiarch-USB.img of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

Then, I booted the system from the grub rescue CD.

First thing, I chose enable LVM support, then load the encrypted volume.
Then lastly, show available boot options.
I chose the correct boot option, and the system booted up normally.
Removing the flash disk, the system fell back to grub.
I booted the system again, then ran the following commands:

```
sudo grub-install

sudo grub update
```

Then rebooted. Everything was restored.
Hope that this can help someone.