# grub bootloader with LUKS encryption - stuck

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader

I think the vmlinuz file got removed from /boot directory, my ubuntu was installed using LUKS inside VM within bhyve on freebsd. I am not able to boot machine, once i power on that VM within bhyve grub console shows up, i was going thru the post > [GRUB Bootloader with root LUKS encryption: Only grub shell](https://superuser.com/questions/1536669/grub-bootloader-with-root-luks-encryption-only-grub-shell)

I had a backup copy of my /boot directory on root fs  /boot_backup/; i was thinking to use vmlinuz from /boot_backup/ directory.

I executed following commands:

```
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
cryptomount -a
set root=(lvm/universe--vg-root)
linux (lvm/universe--vg-root)/boot_backup/vmlinuz-4.4.0-151-generic root=/dev/system/root
initrd (lvm/universe--vg-root)/boot_backup/initrd.img-4.4.0-151-generic
boot
```

System started to boot; i was asked for a password to unencrpyt a drive but then it failed, please see attached log> http://paste.debian.net/1164729/

Can anyone advice how can i resuscitate and boot up that VM?

EDIT:
using these commands it booted up!

```
insmod cryptodisk 
insmod luks 
insmod lvm 
insmod ext2 
cryptomount -a 
set root=(lvm/universe--vg-root) 
linux (lvm/universe--vg-root)/boot_backup/vmlinuz-4.4.0-151-generic root=/dev/mapper/universe--vg-root 
initrd (hd0,msdos1)/initrd.img-4.4.0-151-generic 
boot
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by these commands:

```
insmod cryptodisk 
insmod luks 
insmod lvm 
insmod ext2 
cryptomount -a 
set root=(lvm/universe--vg-root) 
linux (lvm/universe--vg-root)/boot_backup/vmlinuz-4.4.0-151-generic root=/dev/mapper/universe--vg-root 
initrd (hd0,msdos1)/initrd.img-4.4.0-151-generic 
boot
```